# converting NSString to NSData - [NSString dataUsingEncoding] exception

Tags: iphone, json, ios5, nsdata

I was converting NSString to NSData in order to parse by JSON, but I got the following error.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
  reason: '-  [__NSCFDictionary dataUsingEncoding:]: 
  unrecognized   selector sent to instance 0x7987d60'
```

The code is as followings:

```
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]; 
//NSUTF8StringEncoding also failed.
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

In my opinion, this is because str contains new-line character:'\n'.

Am I correct?

Would somebody please help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you tell me your string as well

Comment: I checked in my code, its working fine with sample string which contains \n.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your error says that you are trying to send `dataUsingEncoding:allowLossyConversion:` to an instance of `NSDictionary`, which doesn't know what to do with that selector. Make sure your `str` object is actually a string...

Comment: You're right. It was my mistake. str object is actually NSDictionary as this error says:[__NSCFDictionary dataUsingEncoding:]

Comment: @Harry How did you solve it. Can you please mention. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TaimurAjmal You just ned to change your dictionary object in string like this -         NSString* json = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", responseObject];
and then use this their will be no exception

Answer (score 3):

Try using `NSUnicodeStringEncoding` instead of `NSASCIIStringEncoding`. So replace the line:

```
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

with this:

```
NSData *data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUnicodeStringEncoding];
```

Comment: This is not a proper answer. You need to add more detail to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked with my sample string. **If you could have given me your string then i could have checked out with my following sample code.

```
NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tell me \"where\"\n"
                  "is\n"
                  "wrong"];
NSData *theData = [msg dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString* theString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:theData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

BOOL isValid = [NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:theString];
NSLog(@"Value %d %@",isValid, theString);
```

For me The value is coming 0 and tell me "where"

is

wrong